# Cpu underclock when plugged in

Tags: linux, battery, throttling, cpu-throttling

My laptop underclocks itself when charging(I have Dell original OEM charger). The clock speed drops from 2.2ghz to 500mhz. I've tried configuring the power settings and BIOS settings,disabling speedstep or turbo boost doesn't help. While in Windows, I use Throttlestop application to control my clock speed,but in Linux there isn't a similar application. Can someone please tell me why this is happening and what the permanent solution is for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would try is updating the BIOS, and updating the GPU drivers. If that doesn't work, I would try replacing the charger.

Comment: Changing the charger doesn't work, I've tried updating the BIOS and gpu driver as well